# Compare properties in Array of objects against multiple arrays and return matched elements and unmatched elements to two different new arrays

Tags: node.js, arrays, typescript, loops, object

**Considering this as my array of objects - students**

```
[
  {
    studentName: 'Vishesh Kumar',
    dateOfBirth: '14-03-2023',
    parentName: 'Lalu Kumar',
    examName: 'UPSC CDS',
    dateOfExam: '14-03-1998',
    centerName: 'St Annas High School',
    centerCode: 'RN1001',
    studentEmail: 'Visheshkumar@Gmail.in',
    studentPhoneNumber: 999043139,
    address: 'D-31,Sectory-73,Noida Up India',
    city: 'Noida',
    state: 'UTTAR PRADESH',
    zipcode: 201301
  },
  {
    studentEnrollmentID: 'EN1000006',
    studentName: 'Arnav Singh',
    dateOfBirth: '14-03-2023',
    parentName: 'Arun Singh',
    examName: 'UPSC CDS',
    dateOfExam: '14-03-1998',
    centerName: 'St Annas High School',
    centerCode: 'RN1001',
    studentEmail: 'ArnavSingh@Gmail.in',
    studentPhoneNumber: 6990433540,
    address: 'D-31,Sectory-44,Noida Up India',
    city: 'Noida',
    state: 'UTTAR PRADESH',
    zipcode: 201301
  },
  {
    studentEnrollmentID: 'EN1000004',
    studentName: 'Sanjay Singh',
    dateOfBirth: '14-03-2023',
    parentName: 'Mohan Singh',
    examName: 'UPSC CDS',
    dateOfExam: '14-03-1998',
    centerName: 'St Peters High School',
    centerCode: 'RN1003',
    studentEmail: 'SanjaySingh@Gmail.in',
    StudentPhoneNumber: 9990433538,
    address: 'D-31,Sectory-53,Noida Up India',
    city: 'Noida',
    state: 'UTTAR PRADESH',
    zipcode: 201301
  }
]
```

**Now elements of centerNames[] and centerCodes[] arrays are compared against properties in student objects from above students**

```
const centerNames = ['St Annas High School', 'KV Music School']
const centerCodes = ['RN1001','RN1002']
```

**The code should return two arrays, 1st will have student objects that matched both array elements and 2nd will have student objects that didn't matched either one or both arrays**

**My Existing code looks like loop of if and else running in for loop, which is not ideal if the array size is increasing**

```
    for (student of students) {
      if (student.examCode == examCode) {
        const newStudent = await new Student(student);
        await newStudent.save().then(async (result: any) => {
          studentsUploaded.push(result);
        }).catch(async (error: any) => {
          studentsRejected.push(newStudent);
          errors.push(error);
        });
      } else {
        studentsRejected.push(student);
        errors.push(`${examCode} does not match`);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
const students = [{/*...*/}] // array of students
const centerNames = ['St Annas High School', 'KV Music School']
const centerCodes = ['RN1001','RN1002']
const matched = students.filter(s => centerNames.includes(s.centerName) && centerCodes.includes(s.centerCode))
const unmatched = students.filter(s => !(centerNames.includes(s.centerName) && centerCodes.includes(s.centerCode)))
```

About complexity:

Time complexity is **O(2(n * k * h))** where n is the length of students array and k and h are the length of centerNames and centerCodes. Considering k and h costants, overall complexity is **O(n)** that is the minimum complexity needed to traverse all the students array

Comment: Thank you!. This solution did worked, but I am looking at thousands of records to be processed. How about utilizing multithreading usage with above logic ?

Comment: multithreading with JavaScript? maybe you should consider another programming language for this. you could anyway split the Array in multiple subarrays and spawn a process for each subarray. This would not change nothing about time complexity anyway. also you Need to consider the overead to required to split the Array and to pass data between processes. If you Need a very fast solution you should change language. Or change the date strutture